# Older version of JSON file being read in Python

Tags: python, json, file, mismatch

I'm trying to read a json file from a different folder however the values in it are of an older version of the file. However different jsons in the same folder are read correctly.
And if i copy apply.json to my pwd it is working correctly in that case.
For example -

```
'''In the json:
   AmountMax : 0
When read in python:
   AmountMax : 90'''

with open("../frontend/src/components/Presets/apply.json") as infile:
    settings_data = json.load(infile)
    print(settings_data)
```

I'm completely clueless as to how or why this is happening, any suggestion or help would be great thanks. I've tried making sure the paths are correct and even recreated the file.

Edit:
Here are the outputs as follows

```
apply.json -
{
  "Active": "Preset 0",
  "reqAmountMin": 0,
  "reqAmountMax": 0
}

Python Output reading apply.json from orignal folder -
{'reqAmountMin': 0, 'reqAmountMax': 90}

Python Output reading apply.json copied to pwd -
{'Active': 'Preset 0', 'reqAmountMin': 0, 'reqAmountMax': 0}
```

Comment: It can only be that you're confused about what file is being opened

Comment: try using absolute path names so you can isolate that the file you're intending to read, is in fact the one being read

Comment: Delete that file and check if your code still works. It might just be picking up a different copy because of incorrect path.

Comment: changing it to the absolute path worked but i have to run it on a server which will have a different path, thus I'd prefer an alternative to using the absolute path

Comment: Python does not have the ability to read "older versions of a file". It reads whatever bytes are stored at the path you give it. If an absolute path works, then your relative path is simply "relative to the wrong location". So find out which dir Python is in when your script runs, and fix your relative path so it works with respect to that location.

Comment: What is the name of your python file and how are you running your code? The relative path that you are using in your code is applied to your cwd, not the location of your code file.

Comment: loan.py running it in pycharm, also tried running via command line, correct I have factored that in and set the relative path

Answer (score 2):

Check Working Directory

```
import os
print("Current Working Directory:", os.getcwd())
```

If the script is not in the same directory as the JSON file( your case), you might need to adjust the relative path accordingly.

```
import json

file_path = "/absolute/path/apply.json"

with open(file_path) as infile:
    settings_data = json.load(infile)
    print(settings_data)
```

Replace
**"/absolute/path/apply.json"**
with the actual absolute path to the file.

Comment: I have verified using the absolute path works, but since this is hosted on a server i would prefer being able to use the relative path, which I've verified is correct but still raises the issue above

Comment: @AverageGuy if you still have a problem with reading the wrong content, your "verified" path is obviously still incorrect.  It's probably a misunderstanding of your current working directory, which this answer tells you how to find.